# Using Webpack for Nativescript release elements not found

Tags: webpack, nativescript

I'm trying to build using webpack for nativescript. I'm getting a lot of errors. It appears it doesn't know what the nativescript elements are.

```
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI) : Can't bind to 'text' since it isn't a known property of 'Label'. ("ecked" [id]="item.id" (tap)="toggle($event)" class="far option-circle"></Button>
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI)     <Label col="1" [ERROR ->][text]="item.text" textWrap="true" class="option-label"></Label>
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI) </GridLayout>")
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI) : 'GridLayout' is not a known element:
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI) 1. If 'GridLayout' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI) 2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("]="item.checked && checkedCorrect ? 'visible' : 'collapse'" class="option-correct fas"></Label> -->
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI) [ERROR ->]<GridLayout #optionGrid rows="auto" columns="80,*" class="option-grid" >
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI)     <Button col="0" [text]="")
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI) ERROR in vendor.js from UglifyJs
[19-06-12 10:36:47.864] (CLI) Unexpected token: keyword «const» [vendor.js:188046,46]
```

Comment: Have you included `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` in your module?

Comment: I have this in my app.module.ts:schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]

Comment: You would need it in every feature module too.